# Laravel date error in query builder after parsing the date too

Tags: laravel, date

I am using query builder to fetch some data but for the `created_at` date I am using `Carbon::parse()`, but it's giving me error something like this:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this?

My query:

```
Carbon::parse(DB::table('students_attendances')
            ->join('students_classes', 'students_attendances.class_id', '=', 'students_classes.id')
            ->select('students_attendances.id', 'students_classes.class_name', 'students_attendances.created_at')
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get())->toCookieString();
```

Comment: What are you trying to parse? Is it a valid date? I.e. trying to parse `Carbon::parse("NotADate")` will likely throw that error.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Comment: the result from the query is collection of rows , that is what's wrong

Comment: Yeah, you can't use `Carbon::parse()` on a `Collection`, which is what you're getting back from `DB::table(...)->get()`.

Comment: so what will be the solution ?

Comment: Loop your results and parse each record's `created_at`? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish though. Also, if you use proper Laravel models, `created_at` and `updated_at` are already `Carbon` instances.

Comment: Yes thats what i want